# Python3 How to print a statement that takes values derived from a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, printing, boolean

I need help in printing out a statement that provides the respective allocated weights of A and B where the Sharpe ratio is the highest; which was derived from the data frame.

What I have done so far:

Input

```
efficient_df = pd.DataFrame({'Weights_A':weighted_A, 
                             'Weights_B':weighted_B, 
                             'Portfolio Return': port_ret,
                             'Portfolio Std Dev': port_std,
                             'Sharpe Ratio': sharpe_ratio
                              })
print (efficient_df.head())
print('\n')

sharpe_highest = efficient_df[efficient_df['Sharpe Ratio'] == efficient_df['Sharpe Ratio'].max()]
print('Optimal portfolio details: ')
print(sharpe_highest)
```

Output

```
   Weights_A    Weights_B     Portfolio Return  Portfolio Std Dev  Sharpe Ratio
0        0.00        1.00              0.001933          0.017561          0.110081
1        0.01        0.99              0.001928          0.017386          0.110916
2        0.02        0.98              0.001924          0.017212          0.111760
3        0.03        0.97              0.001919          0.017040          0.112612
4        0.04        0.96              0.001914          0.016869          0.113472


Optimal portfolio details : 
    Weights_A  Weights_B    Portfolio Return  Portfolio Std Dev  Sharpe Ratio
51        0.51        0.49         0.001692            0.01148      0.147348
```

What I need is a statement which goes like:

```
The best allocation is 0.51 of A and 0.49 of B.
```

However, the code below did not work as intended.

```
print('The best allocation is ', weighted_A == efficient_df['Sharpe Ratio'].max(), 'of A and ', weighted_B == efficient_df['Sharpe Ratio'].max(), ' of B.')
```

Result

```
The best allocation is  False of A and False of B.
```

Comment: In your print statement, you try to print the results of a logical statement. Using the `weighted_A == `, you check whether the value of `weighted_A` is equal to the maximum of that column. It returns (and prints) `False`, as this is the correct answer. If you want to print the maximum, just delete the conditions (`weighted_A == ` and `weighted_B ==`). Then, the maxima are printed.

Comment: Hi @MartinWettstein I have made the amendments by removing the conditions but now it just returns like:
`The best allocation is  0.14734845198282917 of A and  0.14734845198282917  of B.` Which is not what I needed, because I need the weights respective to the highest sharpe ratio; in this case is 0.51 and 0.49 respectively.

Comment: Then, use them in the print statement. You have already computed them. `print(sharpe_highest.at[0,'Weights_A'])` should print 0.51, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get booleans (False and True) instead of the floats you want because you use "==" which necessarely returns a boolean.
Except if I misunderstood, you must not use '==' to get the output that you want.

```
print('The best allocation is ', weighted_GS == eff_portfolio_df['Sharpe Ratio'].max(), 'of GS and ', weighted_FB == eff_portfolio_df['Sharpe Ratio'].max(), ' of FB.')
```

Answer (score 4):

You are just printing boolean values instead of actual values.

(Assuming there's only one row with max "Shrape Ratio")

```
sharpe_highest = efficient_df[efficient_df['Sharpe Ratio'] == efficient_df['Sharpe Ratio'].max()]
```

then Simply print:

```
print('The best allocation is ', float(sharpe_highest.weighted_A), 'of A and ', float(sharpe_highest.weighted_B), ' of B.')
```